# Python + PowerPoint: Change Unlinked Charts to Embedded

Tags: python, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint file with linked or unlinked charts (from an excel). How can I automatically change every single chart to be embedded instead to be linked (via PowerPoint itself or via python)?

Thank you.

Comment: `python-pptx` won't be much help with that particular job. I'd look into a VBA solution or perhaps a Python win32com solution that manipulates the PowerPoint application directly.

Comment: it requires a lot of work. Even with VBA/win32com. Excel charts and PowerPoint charts objects are similar but not the same. object names/properties are just so slightly different to make you go mad. Do not do it.